# Windows 10 MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, bsod

My wife's computer has been having blue screens for some time now, and I believe it was caused by my reckless use of snappy drivers, but honestly it could be something else too.

The computer is experiencing MEMORY_MANAGEMENT blue screens quite frequently. I'm unsure if this is related, but the computer is also experiencing freezing, where the mouse still moves, but none of the applications can be used.

Last night I ran memtest on the computer's memory, and it came up with 1024 errors on one the tests of the first pass. So I ran memtest on every ram module individually and none of them came up with errors after a pass, except one of the modules that the computer wouldn't even start with when it was plugged in. The computer's lights on the mouse and keyboard would just flicker, and the monitor would say no signal.

Here's what I have done:

- Memtest RAM
- Wiped Drive, and reinstalled Windows 10
- Changed Power Supply
- Changed Graphics card and Drivers
- Updated BIOS and cleared CMOS

I'm wondering if anyone knows what could be going on with my wife's computer?

Specs:

- Motherboard: msi 970a-g46
- CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965
- GPU: Radeon HD 7950
- RAM: Gskill 8 GB 1600 MHz x 3 DDR3
- PSU: XFX 750W
- Drives: M4 SSD 128 GB & WDC Black 1 TB

Here is the WhoCrashed analysis of the Blue screens:
[image: WhoCrashed analysis of the blue screens]
[(Click for full-sized image — warning: it is 1920×1080.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SBOd.png)

Comment: Remove the module that failed memtest and test with the other two together. If it passes memtest like that, try booting Windows with just those modules. The motherboard doesn't have triple-channel RAM so there is no performance advantage in running with three modules anyway.

Comment: I have removed the 4th module that was faulty, but I will remove one more so that it is dual channel, and then run memtest for a pass. I will reply with the details of the test in about an hour

Comment: I thought you had three modules total? 

n.b.: Whocrashed is pretty useless.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was misleading, I have 4 modules, but one was found to have errors, so I am not using it anymore. The memtest was a lot faster then expected, because it found 2 errors in the first few minutes. Does this mean that one of those 2 peices is faulty?

Comment: One or perhaps both are faulty. Or, if you tested them together, perhaps they are incompatible with each other... or with the particular slots you tested them in (it happens). At the moment it is unclear to me exactly what you've tested and what's failed. You should be keeping a log - which modules in which slots failed or passed, and in what combinations.

Comment: Okay I swapped one of the ones that had an error, and I ran a full pass and I didn't get any errors. So I will run the computer for a while and see if I hit anymore errors.

If this fixed it, thank you for your help :)